# How to make such a button click effect?

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, flutter-animation, mobile-development

This effect is similar to a fast-growing rectangle. Because it’s clear that it’s not just round ripples. It even exists in the google play market as in video.

1. https://youtu.be/ttYRc_zem00
2. https://youtu.be/8d-ki6kDgqg

How to do it using flutter?

(RaisedButton, MaterialButton have ripple effect (circle), but not sort of rectangle compared to that)

Comment: `class RectangleSplash extends InteractiveInkFeature { ...`

Comment: so do you know how to implement it?

Comment: ..... No, sir =(

Comment: check how they did it with [InkSplash](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/80b526ea62/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_splash.dart#L98)

Comment: But I think this is a ready-made widget, because many applications have such an effect

Comment: I don't think so, I checked the sources and did not find any

Comment: But look, the SleepCycle application also has such an effect! How so?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAUvskohPww&feature=youtu.be

Comment: maybe they all use some 3rd party library, but i am sure the flutter public SDK does not have such effect, btw what is so hard in extending `InteractiveInkFeature`?

Comment: Does the Android SDK contain this?

Comment: contains what? `InteractiveInkFeature`?

Comment: No, that effect

Comment: we are talking about flutter, so what android has to do with that?

Comment: You said that flutter SDK does not have effect, and I asked you, maybe then Android SDK has effect. Man :D

Comment: i said that you can easily make it in flutter by extending `InteractiveInkFeature` - just like [InkSplah](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/80b526ea62/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_splash.dart#L98) is implemented

Comment: what "pain" do you mean? i gave you sources for `InkSplah`- it uses [Canvas.drawCircle](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/80b526ea62/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_splash.dart#L226) (line #226) so simply follow that code and draw any kind of rectangle you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) widget to achieve the same result.

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () {//doSomething},
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text("Press me"),
              ),
            )
```